# Filters in VTK for exact vessel segmentation

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, vtk

I do not want to use `ITK` for segmentation .Is there any filters in `VTK` to perform precised vessel segmentation for MIP(Maximum intensity projection)Dicom images.

I tried by installing itk but i have done my code in `visual studio 8` and the latest version of itk is not supported in VS-8.So i imported my vs-8 project to Visual studio 2015,but there are so many errors in them ,i spend many days correcting that error but no use.

That's why i am asking whether there any `filters` in `VTK` to segment the `blood vessels`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VTK is mostly used for visualization and less for processing the data.
What you are looking for is called a "vesselness filter". There are a few implementations of such a filter on github:
https://github.com/search?q=vesselness+filter
The first one, https://github.com/ntnu-bioopt/libfrangi, seems to use only openCV so I guess that could be a good choice for you if you want to limit your dependencies.

Edit:
There is a library called VMTK for vessels analysis. It's based on VTK and it includes a vesselnessfilter. You can directly input VTK image data, so I guess that's the closest framework that can find! Also some other features of the library might be of interest to you.
Look here: http://www.vmtk.org/doc/html/classvtkvmtkVesselnessMeasureImageFilter.html